# How to avoid a user sorting by column in a Power BI matrix

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

How can I prevent users from sorting a column in a matrix in Power BI?

Can't find an option to deselect this feature.

Comment: Agree. People click around and then don't understand what happened.

Answer (score 0):

I think its not possible for the moment, Previously some  users added as a suggestion.

Probably it will release with new version.